# Obtener registros solo cuando es mayor la diferencia entre fechas

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Teniendo una tabla de la siguiente manera:

| ID | Fecha_registro |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-03-10 13:35:40 |
| 2 | 2022-03-08 13:35:40 |
| 3 | 2022-03-08 13:35:40 |
| 4 | 2022-03-10 13:35:40 |
| 5 | 2022-03-08 13:35:40 |

Como puedo obtener los registros donde la diferencia de la Fecha_registro y la Fecha actual es mayor a 48 hrs, por ejemplo solo obtener los registros con ID 2, 3 y 5, ya que ya han pasado mas de 48 hrs a la fecha de hoy 2022-03-11 02:54:00

Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para conseguir los registros con fechas anteriores a hace dos días tienes que usar la siguiente SQL.

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE Fecha_registro < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
```

Comment: Gracias, era justo lo que nesecitaba!

Comment: Esto es para MySQL, como podria ser para SQL SERVER?

Comment: @DavidSolanoRojas no estoy seguro al completo, pero en principio yo entiendo que si